# getting text from EditText in Android on click of button

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Hi I am working on calculator in android.
I am having a EditText in wchich no will displayed depending on click of particular no.for example when user press 1 it will display 1.now when user clicks on 2 it will display 12 and so on.

i have things like this

```
  public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

   public static int no1=0,no2=0,op=0,flag=0;
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    EditText display1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.display);    


     Button one= (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);  
     one.setOnClickListener(this);
   }


public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v.getId()==R.id.one)
    {
        switch(flag)
        {
        case 1:no1*=10+1;display1.setText(no1);
        case 2:no2*=10+1;display1.setText(no2);
        }


    }
```

but here i am getting error as "display1 cannot be resolved".

any solution to make work..??

Comment: u want to get text or set text.

Comment: @nikhil declare your edittext globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes a complete code example helps:

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

   private int no1=0;
   private int no2=0;
   private int op=0;
   private int flag=0;
   private EditText display1;

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);


     display1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.display);    


     Button one= (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);  
     one.setOnClickListener(this);
   }


    public void onClick(View v) {

      if(v.getId()==R.id.one)
      {
        switch(flag)
        {
        case 1:no1*=10+1;display1.setText(no1);
        case 2:no2*=10+1;display1.setText(no2);
        }


   }
}
```

Basically you want to declare display1 as a private instance variable. The other variables do not need to be static, and should probably be declared private. And declarations formatted on separate lines for improved readability.

Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's only available in your onCreate method. Declare it as a field in your class.

```
private EditText display1;
```

Comment: i tried to move buttons and edittext into the class.but its throwing null pointer exception

Comment: Did you move the whole initialization into the class? You only move the edittext, like I have done it in the answer, but still doing: display1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.display); in the oncreate method.

Comment: i tried it both ways.but i am getting same runtime error

Comment: do it like J Steven Perry just posted :)

Answer (score 0):

Declare both your EditText and Button globally.

Answer (score 0):

It should be better to keep a string showing in the EditText so that you have no difficulties appending and erasing. Then you can parse it to an integer so that you will be able to do math with it.

First you should declare your buttons and edit text globally:

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
     private EditText display1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.display);    
     private Button one= (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
     private Button two= (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
```

If you have the button label set as the number you can use it like this:

```
public void onClick(View view){
    display1.setText(display1.getText.toString() +  ((Button) view).getText().toString());
}
```

That way, you can append the numbers to the end of the string in the display. If you want to use the number it's showing, you can use the following code:

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(display1.getText().toString());
```

Comment: By calling findViewById when the instance is created, you are completely bypassing the Activity lifecycle. I would be surprised if this code even works (probably throws NPE).

Comment: @JStevenPerry You are right. They should be only declared there and then call findViewById() in the onCreate method. Thanks for pointing it out.